# Slides JS, portrait orientation Image

Tags: vertical-alignment, centering, landscape-portrait, responsive-slides, slidesjs

I have Slides JS set up on my responsive site. But I'm not able to show the image in a portrait size. 
Does anyone know of any way to get Slides JS to preserve the aspect ratio and adjust the width of the image based on the max-height?

My slide div is:
width: 760 and height: 560: If I have a image width a size of w=320px and h=560px. It scales the image width up to 760px.

My Site: 
http://gaetan.alexandreessayie.com/wp/?p=47&lang=en

thanks for any advise. 
Carol

Answer (score 1):

You need to make some changes in your js file. Find the following code:

```
e(".slidesjs-control",n).children().addClass("slidesjs-slide").css({position:"absolute",top:0,left:0,width:"100%",zIndex:0,display:"none",webkitBackfaceVisibility:"hidden"});
```

and try to change *"width: 100%*" to *"height: 100%"*.